# Using recursive function to read lines of a txt file

Tags: c++, recursion, ifstream

I'm quite new to c++ and im trying to figure out how to use recursive function to read a .txt file and to save them in a string. I want the function to return a value of true when the reading is finished. I've tried to find solutions on the internet but so far no luck. I've tried the following:

```
void readFile(ifstream& stream, vector<string> v)
{
    if (stream.eof()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        string line;
        getline(stream, line);
        v.pushback(line);
        readFile(stream, v);
    }
}
```

Note that I want to use these parameters and I don't want to change them

Comment: Recursion to read a text file? Well, this is stackoverflow after all...

Comment: You clearly havent tried this, otherwise you would know that it wont compile. Why dont you try it first?

Comment: Also there are no question marks, so what is your question ... ?

Comment: Better if you share the problem you are facing. What part s not working ?

Comment: check for error after getline.  Return bool from void. the vector is passed by copy. With some minor fixes this would technically be "a recursive function to read a file", and because it is tail recursive, most compilers would fix the big problem here (that there is no reason to use recursion for this).

Comment: @KennyOstrom Not to mention that it pushes each line to a different temporary vector

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername That was mentioned: `the vector is passed by copy`

Comment: @Ben Sorry, must've overlooked this

Comment: I'm curious about the nature of your question, too? Is your issue about compilation or method? Like @flatmouse mentioned, recursion would work but is unnecessary in this case. Why not read each line in simple sequence? Not to mention the issue of killing the stack memory for excessively large files.

Comment: May be he is curious to play with recursion

Comment: @flatmouse While this approach is terrible, tail recursion nicely takes care of the stack issue if properly implemented. And you're a SCHEME developer who just can't face the light.

Comment: @Shasha99 and that's why we invented the Fibonacci sequence. :)

Comment: `if(stream.eof())` will bring you grief. It is the recursive version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @DavidLively [λ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283081/1460794)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not passing reference to the vector, So even if you push_back() the line, it won't persist once that particular call is over.

I am assuming that you have already opened the file:

```
int main()
{
   ifstream f;
   f.open("input.txt");
   cout<<readFile(f);

}
```

So you have 2 options:

1. Either pass the vector by reference.
2. Or don't pass the vector at all. You may keep it in arguments if you have strict requirements, but you are not supposed to use this. And return the line read by that call. Return ""  when eof() is reached.  Do something like this:

   ```
   string readFile(ifstream& stream, vector<string> v){
      if(stream.eof())
         return "";

      string line;
      getline(stream, line)
      return line + "\n" + readFile(stream, v)
   }
   ```

Comment: It's worth noting that, with a large file, this may have some pretty severe perf cost. Every time you concatenate a string, it is potentially reallocated and copied, then the new parts copied into the new buffer. If you're reading a 10k line file, that will hurt. A 100k-line file would be unusable. But, the basic principle is there. Still, I wonder what  possible reason one would have for reading a file this way.

Comment: We could do this all day. Really last one.

Comment: @DavidLively, yes you are absolutely right. The files lines should be read and then consumed or should be stored in some mutable DS if file is not that large. But it seemed like he is stuck in recursion.

Comment: I know he doesn't want to change the parameters, but would it stop being recursive if he used `vector<string>& v` ?

Comment: No, but i think he wants his recursive approach to be corrected. Its not making any sense BTW. Still ...

Comment: Maybe the official response should be **"Don't do that. Pursue a  career in agriculture."**

Comment: No, we should not underestimate. I still remember my old days.

Answer (score 0):

Problems that immediately jump out at me:

1. `v` is passed by value. This means a lot of copies, copying, and no changes to the original `v`. This needs to be changed to pass by value: `void readFile(ifstream& stream, vector<string> & v)`
2. `if (stream.eof())` will always allow [reading one line past the end of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) with unpredictable results. Something like `if (!std::getline(stream, line))` would resolve this, but a better solution will follow.
3. You can't `return true` from a `void` function.
4. Needless stack killer. A large file will quickly eat up the whole stack or whatever the implementation uses as an automatic datastore.

Possible implementation:

```
void readFile(std::istream& stream, std::vector<std::string> & v)
{
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(stream, line))
    {
        v.push_back(line);
        readFile(stream, v);
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. `istream` in place of `ifstream`. This allows a wider variety of inputs and testing with a `stringstream`.
2. Resolving point 1 above `v` is passed by reference.
3. Resolving point 2 above, `line` is pushed into `v` and the recursive call is made only if data was read from `stream`. If no data was read, `v` is not updated and the recursion ends.
4. There is no reliance on `using namespace std;`. This removes a common source of hard to spot errors.
5. This will still kill the stack, but it will kill it more slowly. This is recursion so nothing can stop the eventual stack overflow if given sufficient input.